# can't return a list with desired order from a python function

Tags: python, list, function, args

wanna write a code that would add to burgerlist the items of my_order with the following order: first and last element of burgerlist should be bread, second and pre-last element should be mayonnaise(if it exist among the arguments while calling function), then beef / chicken, then vegitables. 
pls help to understand what to change here

```
def my_odrer(*g):
    ingredients = [['long_bread', 'circle_bread'], ['mayonnaise', 'ketchup'], ['beef', 'chicken'],
                   ['cucumber', 'tomato', 'onion']]

    burgerlist = []
    for i in g:

        if i in ingredients[0]:
            burgerlist.insert(0, i)
        elif i in ingredients[1]:
            burgerlist.insert(1, i)
        elif i in ingredients[2]:
            burgerlist.append(i)
        elif i in ingredients[3]:
            burgerlist.append(i)

    if burgerlist[1] == 'mayonnaise':
        burgerlist.append(burgerlist[1])

    burgerlist.append(burgerlist[0])

    return burgerlist


print(my_odrer('circle_bread', 'beef', 'tomato', 'mayonnaise', 'ketchup'))
```

the output is: `['circle_bread', 'ketchup', 'mayonnaise', 'beef', 'tomato', 'circle_bread']`

but I want to get: `['circle_bread', 'mayonnaise', 'ketchup', 'beef', 'tomato','mayonnaise', 'circle_bread']`

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: `*g` though this is valid I would not recommend it. Pass a list and treat it as a list. Variable arguments has its use-cases but this is not it.

Comment: None of your rules say where ketchup goes.

Comment: it returns the same result. if  Iremove 'ketchup' it works properly, i guess something is wrong in here

elif i in ingredients[1]:
            burgerlist.insert(1, i)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to know where ketchup is supposed to go, so that I can write my answer correctly.

Comment: I assumed that it goes before the meats, since that's where you have it in the desired results.

Comment: sorry, just saw the question. the ketchup should be placed after mayonnaise, if mayonnaise exists in g, if there is no mayonnaise, than ketchup goes right after the bread

Comment: @Barmar by the way your code  doesn't add any bread

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. BTW, comments about an answer belong at the answer, not below the the quesiton.

Comment: sorry, only 2days in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 lists containing the ingredients that should be at the beginning, middle, and end. Then concatenate them to produce the final result.

```
def my_odrer(*g):
    breads = {'long_bread', 'circle_bread'}
    condiments = {'ketchup'} # mayonnaise not included, since it's handled specially
    meats = {'beef', 'chicken'}
    vegetables = {'cucumber', 'tomato', 'onion'}

    beginning = []
    middle = []
    end = []

    for item in g:
        if item in breads:
            beginning.append(item)
            end.append(item)

    if "mayonnaise" in g:
        beginning.append("mayonnaise")
        end.insert(-1, "mayonnaise")

    for item in g:
        if item in condiments:
            middle.append(item)
    for item in g:
        if item in meats:
            middle.append(item)
    for item in g:
        if item in vegetables:
            middle.append(item)

    return beginning + middle + end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but is it good to create so many variables? can't we find a solution with one list that would contain lists of ingredients in it? also can't we add all the resuts in one list not in 3 lists?

Comment: If you're going to hard-code specific list indexes, it's better to just make them different variables. Lists are useful when you treat all the elements consistently, not when you have different rules for each element.

Comment: Why do you think `item in ingredients[0]` is better than `item in breads`?

Comment: i mean don't we use more storage when we creat more variables? maybe I'm wrong I thought I should try to solve tasks by creating less variables, that's why I decided to have one list for all ingredients.

Comment: No, the storage is about the same. A reference to a list takes the same space whether it's from another list or a variable. There's a little bit of extra memory for the variable itself, but unless you have millions of them it's negligible.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I added an additional condition in your final if statement.

```
def my_odrer(*g):
ingredients = [['long_bread', 'circle_bread'], ['mayonnaise', 'ketchup'], ['beef', 'chicken'],
               ['cucumber', 'tomato', 'onion']]

burgerlist = []
for i in g:

    if i in ingredients[0]:
        burgerlist.insert(0, i)
    elif i in ingredients[1]:
        burgerlist.insert(1, i)
    elif i in ingredients[2]:
        burgerlist.append(i)
    elif i in ingredients[3]:
        burgerlist.append(i)

if burgerlist[1] == 'mayonnaise':
    burgerlist.append(burgerlist[1])
elif burgerlist[2] == 'mayonnaise':
    burgerlist[1], burgerlist[2] = burgerlist[2], burgerlist[1]
    burgerlist.append(burgerlist[1])

burgerlist.append(burgerlist[0])

return burgerlist
```

Comment: it doesn't return the items with the desired order: vegitables should be after beef. I guess I need to add more conditions like you did